# what is the error in my shell script code?

Tags: shell

```
echo "Enter the value"

read x

echo "Enter the value of power"

read n

sum=1

i=1

while [ $i -le $n ]

do

sum=`expr $sum \* $x`

i=`expr $i + 1`

done

echo "The value of $x power $n is $sum"
```

IN some systems its working.
But in my lab some systems it is showing the following two line error

```
7b.sh:7: [:expr : unexpected oprerator
```

the value of 2 power 3 is expr $sum * $x
i tried but no result

Comment: An obvious thing to do is to isolate the difference between  a system it's working on and one where it fails.

Comment: In addition to @NoufalIbrahim: It may be a difference between zsh, bash, ...

Answer (score 0):

if you make that change :

```
while [ $i -le $n ]

do

sum=$(expr $sum \* $x)

i=$(expr $i + 1)

done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15056097)

Comment: @Skadia: The user did not specify what shell he is using. From the error message, it could be Posix shell or - less likely - Bourne shell. If it were Bourne shell, your process substitution would not work. If it is Posix shell, process substititution is not needed. A simple `sum=$(($sum*$x))` would be sufficient.